# iTunes Connect yellow warning icon

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-watch

What does the yellow warning symbol beside my build number on iTunes Connect mean?

Will my app get rejected because of this?

I'm submitting an app with an [apple-watch](/questions/tagged/apple-watch) extension.

[image: build error image]

Thanks

Comment: If your app gets rejected by Apple, they'll usually provide a description of what you need to fix, and how you need to do it. If it's something small then they might just fix it for you and email you about the changes/fixes they made to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there because Testflight doesn't support WatchKit extensions right now. You can still submit without any issues. I've done it numerous times.

Comment: My app doesn't have watchkit target, but still the warning symbol shown for the build and the warning icon is not clickable to see the description.